# How to follow this Xcode tutorial?

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode version 3.2.2 but the tutorial at this site was made for an older version of Xcode. I tried to follow this tutorial but like the tutorial says steps 12-18 don't make sense for newer versions of Xcode. I can't drag .h files into the .xib window in Interface Builder. How would steps 12-18 be different?

[Learn Cocoa II](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_cocoa_two/)

Comment: A link to the actual tutorial might help. It's kind of hard to deduce what steps 12-18 are otherwise. Not impossible, of course, just a tad more work otherwise.

Comment: There is a link at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Interface Builder:

1. Drag from the library an **Object**
2. Select it in the xib window
3. In the Inspector, click the blue 'i' button at the top right
4. Change Object's class to AppController

The rest (from step 13 onwards) seems pretty straightforwards.